# How create a link from a parameter in React component?

Tags: reactjs

In a React.js I have a variable that contains a url.

```
let linkab = 'www.example.com/about';

<Router><Link to={linkab}>About</Link></Router>
```

but this code adds localhost to the address on the link like this:

```
http://localhost:1985/www.example.com/about
```

how can I get the real link without localhost in the beginning?

Comment: Did you try by simply using an anchor tag?

`<a href="www.example.com/about" target="_blank" />`

is there any specific requirement to use React-Router's `<Link />`?

Comment: @RejoChandran I have to use the variable because it changes in different situation. So I have to use this variable that store a url inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually we use `Link` when we want to navigate to a different route in the same application.

But since you need want to navigate the user outside of your application `anchor` tag would be the best suitable one

```
<a href={linkab}>About</a>
```

Also, if you the provided url is not having any `http` or `https` protocol then by default it'll be considered as `relative path`. Hence, the provided url will be appended to the current browser address/url. So, in your case if you provide something like below then it will redirect to that url on click.

```
let linkab = 'http://www.example.com/about'; 
or
let linkab = 'https://www.example.com/about';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use regular `<a target="_blank" href={linkab}>To external site</a>` tag, no need to use `Link`. And add `https://` before url.

Comment: I used your code but when I click on the link it gives the same result as I wrote above. Your code works if it is a string and not a variable that contains a url.